# Check list of numbers is a subset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python pandas dataframe like this:

```
data = ['13,12', '8, 7', '12,1', '7', '2,6']
index = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'

col = ['colnames']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns = col)

df

     colnames
a    13,12
b    8, 7
c    12,1
d    7
e    2,6
```

I want to see if the numbers in the 'colnames' column are in the following list of numbers:

7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 23, 24, 25, 26.

I tried to use the following function to check if this is true and if so, it should return 'good' and otherwise, should return 'poor':

```
def quality_check(qaulity):

     for numbers in str(quality):
            if numbers  in [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 23, 24, 25, 26]:
                return "good"
            else:
                return "poor"


df['colnames'].map(quality_check)
```

The expected results is:

```
a   good
b   good
c   poor
d   good
e   poor
```

However, this is what I am getting:

```
a    poor
b    poor
c    poor
d    poor
e    poor
```

Does anyone know how to do this or a better way to do it? I really appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this to check all numbers, your function was not checking all the numbers and was comparing `ints` to `strings`:

```
def quality_check(q):
    spl = q.split(",") # split to check both numbers
    if  all(x in  ["7", "8", "9", "10", "12", "13", "15", "23", "24", "25", "26"]for x in  spl):
        return "good"
    else:
        return "poor"
```

Outputs:

```
a    good
b    good
c    poor
d    good
e    poor
Name: colnames, dtype: object
```

As soon as `all` meets an element that is not in the  it will return False.

You can also use `sets` to check for `subsets` also and `map` the elements to `ints`:

```
col = ['colnames']
def quality_check(q):
    spl = map(int,q.split(","))  #  make all ints  and split into individual nums
    if set(spl).issubset( [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 23, 24, 25, 26]):
        return "good"
    else:
        return "poor"
```

You could use sets with the first example also, the elements do not have to be ints.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are comparing strings to integers, which won't work:

```
>>> for n in '123':
...     print n,
...     if n in [1, 2, 3]:
...         print 'yes'
...     else:
...         print 'no'
...         
1 no
2 no
3 no
```